# Можно ли писать сайты на С или C#?

Tags: php, c, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, компиляция

В интернете часто пишут, что делать сайты (серверное программирование) на языках типа С, С++, C#, Фортран, ТурбоПаскаль вроде как нереально, надо делать на языках программирования вроде PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, Java.

Но почему это так и в чем нереальность в интернете до сих пор нет нормального объяснения и многие новички не понимают, я бы даже сказал не знают, поскольку нигде нормально этот вопрос не рассматривается?

Поэтому хотелось бы понять

1. Можно ли делать сайты (далее везде речь пойдет о серверном
   программировании, не клиентском) на С, С++, C#, Фортран, ТурбоПаскаль
   или любых других языках? Или есть какие-то особенности, которые не
   позволяют этого делать или очень сильно усложняют разработку и какие
   это особенности?
2. Правильно ли я понимаю, что для данных языков С, С++, C#, Фортран,
   ТурбоПаскаль на сервере должен стоять компилятор и есть ли он там? Или
   на сервер нужно загружать уже скомпилированную программу, если так он
   сможет ее исполнить или нет?
3. В чем принципиальное преимущество PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, Java
   касаемо серверного программирования против С, С++, C#, Фортран,
   ТурбоПаскаль и любых других языков? Оно вообще есть или в свое время
   сыграл свое дело хороший маркетинг?

Comment: Stackoverflow на ASP.NET сделан...

Comment: ага, особенно ASP.net доказывает, что на сшарп вообще никак

Comment: Если сайт простой - разницы практически нет. Чем больше наворотов, тем нужнее будут более приспособленные, и имеющие кучу готовых решений на разные случаи, языки.

Comment: Тоже интересует этот вопрос, особенно интересно где и как используется ASP.NET

Comment: Facebook по большому счёту таки Си++, у Г. компании тоже много кода на Си++ для веба.

Comment: Почему сайты разделяют в основном серверное программирование на php, а клиентское на javascript. Если разницы нет, то почему не делают и серверное и клиентское программирование на каком-то одном языке, например на одном php (или одном javascript)?

Comment: А вы замените "невозможно" на "мне влом учить язык". Получите ответ. В принципе можно писать хоть на ассемблере. У PHP, Java, Ruby низкий порог обучения, по сравнению с С,С#

Comment: ** почему не делают и серверное и клиентское программирование на каком-то одном языке** - потому, что программа JavaScript исполняется браузером на машине клиента, а PHP скрипты исполняются на машине сервера, интерпретатором PHP. Это две абсолютно разные и непересекающиеся задачи. Хотя, в последнее время, есть попытки затащить JavaScrip на сервер (Node.JS ). Насколько успешно - не берусь судить.

Comment: Нам надо открутить гайку, у нас есть плоскогубцы - универсальный инструмент мы можем им крутить гайки и делать много чего еще, а есть рожковый ключ, он специализированный инструмент, им  откручивать гайки гораздо удобнее, именно по тому, что он создан для этой задачи. Так и с языками, есть универсальные, на них разумеется можно делать cgi, а есть специализированные, на которых это делать гораздо удобнее (кстати почему java попала в этот ряд не ясно, ее место рядом с C#).

Comment: P.S. но если сильно хочется то и гвозди можно забивать ключом, т.е. на php то же можно сделать что угодно, но может быть очень не удобно, потому что сделан он именно как web язык

Comment: Вполне существуют web-сервера со встроенной логикой на сях. Ваш вопрос основан на невереном утверждении.

Comment: @Sergey Т.е. браузер иной язык кроме как javascript не умеет интерпретировать, да? Но что касается серверного программирования, сервер кроме PHP ничего больше интерпретировать не умеет?

Comment: @Mike Насколько я понимаю на php можно сделать что угодно и если есть интерпретатор это будет работать только гораздо медленнее, чем скомпилированная программа, в этом плане принципиальной разницы с компилируемыми языками нет. Но сможет ли сервер обработать компилируемый язык С, С++, C#, Фортран, ТурбоПаскаль? Какие могут при этом возникнуть сложности?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов поясните, пожалуйста. Поэтому вопрос и задан, что неясна причина

Comment: @ПавелИгорев web-сервер просто выполняет по правилам ОС указанный файл. если это скрипт он запускает исполнимый файл интерпретатора и скармливает ему файл (или отдает уже запущенному внутри него интерпретатору), если файл выполнимый сам по себе, то он просто запускается. так что никаких отличий у компилируемых языков нет. главное что бы был скомпилированный файл под платформу с web-сервером

Comment: @ПавелИгорев что объяснять? Я знаю, что есть программы, написанные на C/C++, которые не только являются web-сервером, но и содержат внутри себя реализацию логики сайта. Следовательно, ваше утверждение неверно.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Если я вас правильно понял, вы говорите про какие-то редкие веб-серверы, которых скорее всего не будет на популярных хостингах. Мой вопрос именно про стандартные условия с наиболее популярными веб серверами (по-моему это apache и ngnix)

Comment: @ПавелИгорев вы, наверное, думаете что Apache и nginx написаны не на C/C++? Зря вы это :-)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если сайт написан на php, то ему нужен обязательно интерпретатор, коим является веб сервер (что есть по-умолчанию на хостинге), а сайт написанный на С, С++, C#, Фортран, ТурбоПаскаль в любом случае должен быть уже скомпилирован (поскольку веб сервер компилировать не умеет) и сам являться веб-сервером?

Comment: **думаете что Apache и nginx написаны не на C/C++? Зря вы это :-)** О Господи!!! А на чём же ещё ?! Вы в состоянии САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНО скачать исходный код апача вот отсюда: http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi распаковать архив и посмотреть, на каком языке написан СЕРВЕР апач ? Похоже, Вы просто не понимаете разницу между словами *сервер* и *сайт*. Сервер - это программа, с помощью которой клиенты имеют доступ к сайту. А сайт - это совокупность html страничек.

Comment: **сайт написанный на С, С++, C#** Да не бывает *сайтов* написаных на С. PHP и т.д... Все сайты - это html странички. А PHP, C и т.д. - это программы, с помощью которых генерируются html странички... У-ф-ф-ф !!!

Comment: @Sergey Это понятно, что сайты - это html странички и apache с ngnix на C/C++ , я не об этом. Я как раз и говорю про генерацию этих страничек на сервере. Если я все правильно понял, то на компилируемом языке можно написать программу по генерации статичной страницы без взаимодействия с кем-либо (также заложив в нее и функционал "программы" веб-сервера), например отправить в ответ html код, сгенерированный уже скомпилированной программой.

Comment: @ПавелИгорев "_Мой вопрос именно про стандартные условия_". Так вот вам и отвечают, что в стандартных условиях и apache и nginx могут запускать любую программу. "_если сайт написан на php, то ему нужен обязательно интерпретатор, коим является веб сервер_". нет, не верно, web-сервер интерпретатором не является. он запускает интерпретатор как любую другую откомпилированную программу (которой может быть и не интерпретатор а готовое приложение, написанное на C, например)

Comment: @Mike. А я уж подумал, что у скомпилированного сайта должна быть и функция веб-сервера. Но я кажется понял, что у скомпилированного сайта проблемы с динамикой - придется постоянно перекомпилировать и вообще непонятно как это нормально реализовать (некому отинтерпретировать обновленную информацию)?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев Никаких проблем с динамикой. php-код то же каждый день не правят. вся динамика обычно хранится в БД и она собствено потому и называется динамикой, что берется не готовая откуда то, а создается динамически, т.е. программно, на любом языке

Comment: @Mike тогда реально не вижу разницы в техническом плане, разве что при изменениях надо перекомпилировать

Comment: @Mike ...и что скомпилированная программа должна поддерживать серверное железо

Comment: **огда реально не вижу разницы в техническом плане** В техническом плане разница заключается в том, что РНР код, генерирующий html-страницу можно разместить прямо внутри этой страницы, т.к. этот код почти всегда генерирует только часть html-странички, а вот cgi-программа всегда отделена от генерируемого кода. И это менее удобно в отладке.А доступ к запросу клиента и серверным БД у них абсолютно одинаковый.

Comment: Пффф, вот вам «веб-сайт» на brainfuck, чо уж. Если поставить интерпретатор и скормить файл в апач, то заработает. https://pastebin.com/AmSM3Mxm

Comment: Почитал каменты. Много смеялся. Просто поражают знания "икспертов" о си и паскале, а так же о принципах работы CGI. на си можно делать все, только мозги надо иметь. Да и на паскале тоже. Эти языки имеют огромный набор библиотек для любых применений, что позволяет писать компактные и быстрые приложения. При наличии мозгов, естественно. Только вот с мозгами в вэботрасли очень плохо. PS до появления "чудо-языков" все вэб сервисы писались на си.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> делать сайты на языках типа C, C#, Фортран

На самом деле **абсолютно все** сайты "сделаны" на языке HTML. Другое дело, что все html-странички, из которых и состоят сайты, делятся на две категории:

1. Статичные (неизменные) странички
2. Динамические (постоянно изменяющиеся) странички.

Примером статичных страничек могут быть страницы, содержащие документы - фиксированный текст, который не меняется, а если и меняется то очень редко.

Динамические странички генерируются "на лету", в тот момент, когда пользователь ввел URL этой странички. Примерами могут быть прайс-листы, новостные и погодные сайты, гостевые книги и т.д.

Тенденция такова, что всё больше и больше контента сайта становится динамическим. Естественно, возникает вопрос, какими **средствами** выполняется эта самая генерация html-страничек. Так как сами странички - просто текстовые документы, то для работы с таким форматом данных необходимы средства, хорошо работающие с текстом, строками и символами.

Можно выделить два класса этих средств, выполняющих генерацию контента:

1. Специализированные языки программирования (Perl, PHP,Rust, Go...)
2. Целые системы для генерации содержимого - CMS.

Естественно, что язык С совершенно не подходит для обработки текстовых документов - набор функций для этой цели в нём крайне примитивен. Но если есть желание, можно и  на С написать программу, генерирующую htm-страничку, поместить её в каталог cgi-bin и наслаждаться результатом.

Comment: Это понятно, тут вопрос другой что касается сервера. С браузером вроде разобрались - браузер умеет интерпретировать только JavaScript, поэтому для браузера только JavaScript. А сервер не умеет интерпретировать (исполнять) ничего кроме PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, Java и т.д.? Почему именно эти языки, а не С, С++, C#, Фортран, ТурбоПаскаль? У них реальное преимущество или невозможность использования других языков или так исторически сложилось (маркетинг и т.д.) и реально никто не понимает почему? Согласно википедии, программу генерирующую HTML можно помещать куда угодно, не обязательно в cgi-bin.

Comment: **Почему именно эти языки, а не С, С++, C#, Фортран, ТурбоПаскаль?** - ещё раз повторяю, пишите программу на **любом** языке и размещайте её в каталоге cgi-bin. На вход ей подаётся HTTP запрос от клиента, а на входе у неё должна быть HTML страничка. И никаких других требований к этой программе не предъявляется. Посмотрите в любом справочнике, что такое CGI.

Comment: Но эта программа на любом языке уже должна быть скомпилирована перед загрузкой на сервер, правильно? И в процессе написания программы нужно заложить в нее также и функционал веб-сервера по приему запроса и отправке ответа, правильно? Т.е. на компилируемом языке можно написать генерацию статичной странички, но взаимодействие с пользователем уже будет нереально прописать поскольку нет интерпретатора, а код уже скомпилирован, верно?

Comment: **но взаимодействие с пользователем уже будет нереально прописать поскольку нет интерпретатора, а код уже скомпилирован, верно?** Как раз наоборот. CGI интерфейс был задуман именно для того, что бы создавать **динамический** html. Когда  сервер запускает cgi программу, он передаёт ей HTTP запрос, пришедший от клинета. CGI программа должа проанализировать этот запрос и выдать html, соответствующий именно этому запросу. Изменился запрос - изменился ответ. Кроме того, cgi программа может использовать БД на сервере. Изменилось содержимое БД - изменился html.

Comment: Например, пользователь добавляет новый комментарий на сайте (скомпилированной программе на языке C), который после добавления все увидят. Как эта скомпилированная программа сможет добавить для отображения и в базу данных комментарий - нужно будет снова перекомпилировать? И как она без интерпретатора вообще сможет это сделать? Т.е. логика будет следующая: при принятии определенного тега с классом "комментарий" отправить его сразу в базу данных и добавить этот тег в машинный код скомпилированной программы - как такое возможно? Как он добавится без перекомпилирования?

Comment: Т.е. нужно будет еще и компилятор туда приколачивать (кстати, хостинг такое позволит)? И каждый чих будет постоянно перекомпилироваться? Ладно еще если сайт редко обновляется. А то такой компилятор уже получается как бы извращенная версия интерпретатора.

Comment: Прихожу к выводу, что инфа про вконтакте, facebook и прочие крупные сайты, которые якобы сделаны на C, C++ не соответствует действительности. Думаю они все же написаны на интерпретируемых языках, т.к. сайты постоянно обновляемые (каждую долю секунды там что-то меняется). И не потому что, как некоторые отвечают типа C/C# сложнее PHP, еще часто в интернете пишут, что типа на php пишут лохи, нормальные на C/C++. А потому что технически сложно реализовать.

Comment: **Например, пользователь добавляет новый комментарий на сайте (скомпилированной программе на языке C)** - Вы меня извините, но я ТРЕТИЙ раз повторяю!!! САЙТ - это HTML. А программа на С- это программа, ставшая частью  СЕРВЕРА, благодаря тому, что её поместили в папку cgi-bin. Вы осознаёте разницу между сайтом и сервером ? 

Комментарий  в программе на языке С (и любой другой программе на любом другом языке) не попадёт никогда и никуда. Ни при каких обстоятельствах. Именно потому, что они комментарии. У Вас есть хотя бы минимальный опыт написания программ? На любом языке...

Comment: **определенного тега с классом "комментарий"** - это Вы вообще - о чём?! Да, в HTML есть тэг "комментарий". Но нет никаких "классов". Вы представляете, как  работает HTTP протокол ?

Comment: Опыта нет. Под классом я имел ввиду типа <p class="comment">.. Так вроде разобрался, что чисто технически разницы нет. Я просто как-то неправильно представлял себе, что на лету нужно будет переписывать программу, например, при добавлении комментария, хотя это все не так

Comment: **на лету нужно будет переписывать программ** - нет, разумеется. Любая, толково написанная, программа должна работать при широком наборе входных данных и создавать соответствующий выход. У cgi-программы два входа - HTTP запрос от клиента и все файлы (в том числе - БД), к которым дал доступ провайдер. Например - cgi-программа  считывает показание системных часов и генерирует html-страничку, в которой выводится текущее время.

Одна программа создаёт РАЗНЫЕ html странички. Так - понятнее ?

Comment: Но оно того стоит (программа сайта на компилируемом языке)? скорость обработки на сервере будет чумовая или особой разницы не будет?

Comment: **скорость обработки на сервере будет чумовая** Если не заострять внимание на "программе сайта" которой не бывает в природе, то да, технология Fast-CGI обеспечивает очень высокую скорость генерации HTML.

Comment: **нужно заложить в нее и функционал веб-сервера по приему запроса и отправке ответа, правильно?** Нет, не правильно. Веб-сервер запускает CGI программу и передаёт ей на вход уже принятый запрос пользователя. Программа должна его (запрос) обработать и сгенерировать соответствующий html документ.  Этот документ CGI программа просто пишет в stdout, не заботясь о том, как он попадёт к клиенту. Ну прочитайте же, про технологию CGI !

Comment: Я имел не просто технологию fast-cgi, а где fast-cgi именно скомпилированная программа. По сравнению с тем же fast-cgi php будет быстрее же?

Comment: **По сравнению с тем же fast-cgi php будет быстрее же?** Вопрос не корректен.  Один и тот же PHP может работать и как модуль сервера и как CGI. А CGI бывает обычным и Fast. Очевидно, что когда PHP работает как модуль сервера, то это быстрее, чем чрез GGI.  Посмотрите тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/67475/ Проблема только в том, что и там и тут PHP всё-равно будет проигрывать по скорости скомпилированной программе в CGI.

Answer (score 4):

> Но почему нереально

Реально. Хоть на ассемблере, хоть на фортране, хоть на `bash`. Вопрос в трудозатратах и уровнях абстракции.

> чисто технически сгенерировать html-страницу на сервере можно на любом языке?

Да. Но попробуйте обработать что-то вроде `multipart/form-data` на C/ASM/etc (даже с привлечением сторонних библиотек), и представьте, что это самая примитивная задача в числе тех, которые приходится решать.

P.S. Именно поэтому глупо спрашивать "какой язык учить" - для разных задач подходят разные языки, и нормальный программист должен знать хотя бы пяток из них :)

Comment: Ну, например, написана программа на или C, C#, ее же нужно будет для начала скомпилировать перед загрузкой на хостинг или хостинг сам умеет компилировать? И поймет ли хостинг, как обрабатывать эту программу?  Правильно ли я понял ваш ответ, что писать можно на любом, но это больше времени займет (больше строчек кода)? ps: в программировании не особо.

Comment: @ПавелИгорев Хостинг - это такой же комп как и все остальные с такой же операционкой. Если вам дали доступ в консоль (многие хостинги ее дают) и в системе стоит компилятор C (а на linux системах он есть) то можете спокойно зайти и скомпилировать программу. И она будет работать если в настройках web-сервера хостер разрешил запуск произвольных cgi.

Answer (score 4):

> Можно ли делать сайты (далее везде речь пойдет о серверном программировании, не клиентском) на С, С++, C#, Фортран, ТурбоПаскаль или любых других языках? Или есть какие-то особенности, которые не позволяют этого делать или очень сильно усложняют разработку и какие это особенности?

Можно. Но у всех перечисленных языков кроме C# из коробки ничего для веб-разработки не идёт. Вот статья на хабре, как на ассемблере писать: https://habrahabr.ru/post/318916/.

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что для данных языков С, С++, C#, Фортран, ТурбоПаскаль на сервере должен стоять компилятор и есть ли он там? Или на сервер нужно загружать уже скомпилированную программу, если так он сможет ее исполнить или нет?

Неправильно. Нужен рантайм языка, если он требуется после компиляции программы твоим компилятором. Если ты получил исполняемый файл, то его надо просто запустить.

C# опять немного выделяется, поскольку в .net core что-то сделали не так, как было в классическом C#, где приложение компилировалось в код. Не знаю, что нужно для его исполнения на сервере, но при классическом C# компилятор тоже не нужен.

> В чем принципиальное преимущество PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, Java касаемо серверного программирования против С, С++, C#, Фортран, ТурбоПаскаль и любых других языков? Оно вообще есть или в свое время сыграл свое дело хороший маркетинг?

В php изначально идёт нечто, позволяющее использовать его для написания сайта. Это и куча функций по работе с запросом/ответом, буферизациейи т. д., и встроенный шаблонизатор.

В C# есть устаревший asp.net и более новые asp.net mvc и webapi. Последние два также входят в кроссплатформенный .net core. Писать на них сайты весьма удобно.

Node.js предоставляет низкоуровневый доступ к запросу и ответу и на него давно написаны аналоги распространённых решений по сайтостроению. Наиболее популярен express.

На джаве когда-то было jsp, но оно устарело, что есть сейчас - не знаю.

В си и плюсах нет ничего. Там даже методы для работы с сетью в стандарт не входят, если не ошибаюсь, так что придётся всё делать с нуля и под конкретную платформу (ну или искать готовое - думаю, должно что-то найтись).

Турбопаскаль - старьё с 16-битными программами. Во-первых, понятия не имею, на каких серверах это сможет запуститься, во-вторых, памяти мало - 64 КБ на всё и, вероятно, возможность нарыть до 2 гигов через дальние указатели (это вспоминая borland c++), но мегабайта стека, как в современных программах, точно никто не даст.

Comment: <зануда>не 65, а 64 КБ, и то не полностью, на них мапятся еще векторы прерываний, аппаратные IO-регистры и другая системная муть, так что плюс-минус 48 КБ на страницу</зануда> а вот запустить х16-программу сейчас реально проблема даже на пользовательской машине, не говоря о серверах, в DosBox разве что.

Comment: @rdorn, 64 испавил - что-то я 1000-байтные килобайты взял вместо нормальных)) x16 должно быть совместимо с 2003 сервером (если не путаю), ReactOS и ещё может помочь DosBox. А может и wine умеет?